# Can no longer edit views

Tags: views

I have recently migrated my site to a new hosting company and, since then, I can no longer change the settings in my views. For example, if I wish to edit a field, I can get into it but the REWRITE RESULTS and other sub headings no longer are links and do not open. Creating new fields does the same thing. When I want to add a field I do not get the drop down list that allows me to select the field I want, instead I get a long list of the available fields.

The overall look of the views edit form is no longer Severn but my default theme (Bartik) See the attached picture. There are no drop down lists any longer.

I had that problem very rarely on with the previous hosting company but a refresh generally fixed the issue. Now, it is permanent.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks. :)

[image: Edit form snapshot]

Comment: Any chance you have the "Devel" or "ThemeKey" modules running?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: The Devel module was running. I disabled it, cleared the cache twice. But it's still the same. I changed the DNS back to the old site and all works well there. Re-exported the database to the new site and reset the DNS but the problem reappears. :(